# Loading Assembly only once

Tags: reflection, assemblies, loading, assembly.load

I'm loading an assembly at runtime and the question that arises everytime I call the code is that should I be checking if that particular assembly has loaded already? or does .Net take care of this and one assembly (same version) can only be loaded once? The basic question here is do i have to iterate through a list of loaded assemblies and see if my assembly was already loaded or not?
Thanks

Comment: Im using : System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx): "If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified. "

Comment: This holds true even if you are trying to reflect the current assembly.